# Will Dapps in production be able to buy and use SaaS solutions?

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development, dapps

SaaS services help centralized organizations or apps solve their business problems. For example, Google Apps offers startups as an easy solution for company email and document storage. The sales process is simple because there are a small number of known people making the buying decision - they interact with representatives of the company selling the SaaS service and a decision is made.

Will Dapps in production be able to buy or benefit from SaaS solutions (whether the SaaS solutions are centralized or decentralized)? If so, how will the buying decision be made? How will rollout work?

Comment: Related? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93110/how-would-a-medieval-city-get-cold-drinks